# How to add item in knockout array after loading a partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm new to Knockout and I want to load partial view in my MVC project when users navigate in the site.
The partial view loading is working, but I need to add items to a ko.observable array which render in a list. When I try to push an item, I get the message "nom is undefined.
Here's the view model:

```
var service = function (nom) {
this.nom = ko.observable(nom)
};

var services = ko.observableArray([new service('Hello')]);
var plainteModel = {


  DocumentePar: ko.observable('Michel Bernier'),
  Date: ko.observable('12-12-2016'),





nextStep: function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Plainte/GetSection1',
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        success: function (results) {
            $('#sectionRendering').html(results);

        },
        error: function (error) {
        }
    })
    services.push([new service('Test')]);
    ko.applyBindings(plainteModel, $('#sectionRendering')[0]);

},

prevStep: function () {

}



};

ko.applyBindings(plainteModel);
```

The main view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Plainte";
}
@Styles.Render("~/Content/Plainte")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

<div class="content">

    <div class="sidebar1">
        <div id="sidebarContainer">
            <ul id="sections">
                <li><button>Section 1</button></li>
                <li><button>Section 2</button></li>
                <li><button>Section 3</button></li>
                <li><button>Section 4</button></li>
                <li><button>Section 5</button></li>
                <li><button>Section 6</button></li>
                <li><button>Section 7</button></li>
                <li><button>Section 8</button></li>
                <li><button>Section 9</button></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <ul class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="#">Acceuil</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Plainte</a></li>
            <li class="active">Plainte No.9999</li>
        </ul>
        <div id="controlButtons"><button>Annuler</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button>Enregistrer</button></div>

    </div>

        <div id="sectionRendering">


        </div>




</div>
<div class="navigation">
    <div id="navigationControls">
        <button id="navPrev" data-bind="click: prevStep">Précédent</button><button id="navNext" data-bind="click: nextStep">Suivant</button>
    </div>

</div>

<footer id="plainteFooter">
    <div class="tabsExpanded" onclick="collapseTabs()" id="closeTabsBtn"></div>
    <div id="plainteTabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Pièces jointes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Journal</a></li>

        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
            <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
        </div>

    </div>

</footer>


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Plainte")

}
```

The partial view:

```
    <ul data-bind="foreach: services">
    <li>
        <div>
            <span data-bind="text: nom"> </span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>



            <h2>Plainte</h2>
            <div>Plainte documenté par: <input data-bind="textInput: DocumentePar" /></div>
            <div>Date de l'événement: <input data-bind="text: Date" /></div>

            <button data-bind="click: savePlainte">Sauvegarder</button>

            <button data-bind="click: getPlainteInfo.bind($data,1)">Test getInfo</button>
```

If I remove the line with the push in the nextstep function, everything is OK, I get the main view, the partial view and KO binds everything OK, but if I try to push a new service, I get the message "nom is undefined".

I'm banging my head for 5 hours on this!!

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `services.push([new service('Test')]);` is wrong. You push an item to an array, not an array to an array. So it should be `services.push(new service('Test'));` without the []

Comment: How silly of me, all that time I was searching for something wrong with knockout!! Thanks !!

Comment: Andy - can you please add the answer as an answer, so other people can also benefit thanks :)